# And statements in a return C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out what is going on with the "and" statements in the return line from this sample of code, could someone please tell me what the purpose of putting these "and" statements in the return of a function is?
  if just one of them is false would it return false to the function that called it?

```
return !UsedInRow(board, row, num) && !UsedInCol(board, col, num) &&
       !UsedInBox(board, row - row % 3 , col - col % 3, num);
```

Comment: It's just returning the result of a boolean expression.

Comment: The `&&` operator is part of an *expression*, not a statement. And it works just the same as using logical and `&&` anywhere else.

Comment: Are you asking what a function `AND(x1,x2,...,xn)` where `x` are boolean variables returns? If so, that should be known before starting any programming language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's equivalent to

```
bool a;
a = UsedInRow(board, row, num);
if (a) return false;
a = UsedInCol(board, col, num);
if (a) return false;
a = UsedInBox(board, row - row % 3 , col - col % 3, num);
if (a) return false;
return true;
```

due to the *short-circuiting* nature of the `&&` and the fact that evaluation is from left to right.

(This holds true even if the function parameters are passed *by reference* and modified in the functions, as `&&` is a *sequencing point*.)

Answer (score 0):

if just one of them is false would it return false to the function that called it? The answer is yes.
This will stop the computation of further functions as False AND any value => False.

This will return True or False based on the values returned by the UsedIn* functions.
This is to check whether the number 'num' can be inserted in Suduko. This will check whether the number can be inserted in a given cell provided it is present in that row, column or the box.

Answer (score 0):

`UsedInRow` and `UsedInCol` are both functions returning a `bool` (or a type that can be converted to `bool`). The `&&` operators just chain the return values of the functions together that results into a final `bool` result that yields either `true` or `false` which is then returned.

Note that not all functions in this case have to run because of short-circuit evaluation, that is, if the result one of the three boolean expressions is `false` then (because of the `&&`) the result can't possibly be `true` and thus functions that are not yet evaluated won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works exactly like in an `if` statement. If any of the `Used` functions return true then the whole return value will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

if `!UsedInRow(board, row, num)` this executes to return false then `return` statement will automatically return flase without executing other two statements

if `!UsedInRow(board, row, num)` returns true only then second statement `!UsedInCol(board, col, num)` will get executed and now if it returns false then the `return` statement will return false otherwise third statement will get executed

Now if `!UsedInBox(board, row - row % 3 , col - col % 3, num)` this statement evaluates to be true `return` statement will return true else it will return false

So in order to get true from `return` statement all three conditions should be evaluated to get `true` value

Answer (score -1):

The && operator returns a bool value (true or false) so the expression is equivalent to:

```
if (!UsedInRow(board, row, num) && !UsedInCol(board, col, num) &&
   !UsedInBox(board, row - row % 3 , col - col % 3, num)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

also you may find some sort of these expressions which also holds the same result:

```
return (!UsedInRow(board, row, num) && !UsedInCol(board, col, num) && !UsedInBox(board, row - row % 3 , col - col % 3, num))?true:false;
```